# PHP randomize the order of select option

Tags: php

I have the following select options in my page, which I would like to randomize the order of.

```
<select class="selectpicker1 show-menu-arrow span2" onchange="updatePreview();">
    <option data-content="<img src='img/render/3-thumb.jpg'>" value="3.jpg">three</option>
    <option data-content="<img src='img/render/5-thumb.jpg'>" value="5.jpg">five</option>     
    <option data-content="<img src='img/render/1-thumb.jpg'>" value="1.jpg">one</option>
    <option data-content="<img src='img/render/2-thumb.jpg'>" value="2.jpg">two</option>
    <option data-content="<img src='img/render/4-thumb.jpg'>" value="4.jpg">four</option>   
    <option data-content="<img src='img/render/6-thumb.jpg'>" value="6.jpg">six</option>  
    <option data-content="<img src='img/render/7-thumb.jpg'>" value="7.jpg">six</option>    
  </select>
```

So far I have the following code, but it isn't working, is this the simplest way to randomize the order? and is there a problem with the code?

```
<?php 
  $options=array( '<option data-content="<img src="img/render/3-thumb.jpg">" value="3.jpg">three</option>', 
  '<option data-content="<img src="img/render/5-thumb.jpg">" value="5.jpg">five</option>', 
  '<option data-content="<img src="img/render/1-thumb.jpg">" value="1.jpg">one</option>'); 
  shuffle($options); 
  echo '<select class="selectpicker1 show-menu-arrow span2" onchange="updatePreview();">'; 
  foreach ($options as $picker) { 
  echo '$picker'; } 
  echo '</select>'; ?>
```

Comment: the code is ok and should work.. But you can replace the final foreach loop by: `echo implode('', $options);`

Comment: You only have three of your options in the $options-array. Maybe this is the reason why you don't see that it has been shuffled? Also, '$picker' should not be in quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables don't interpolate when they're inside single-quotes.

```
echo '$picker'; }
```

should simply be:

```
echo $picker; }
```

Also, for fixing the HTML markup, you can simply escape the quotes, like so:

```
'<option data-content=\'<img src="img/render/3-thumb.jpg">\' 
value="3.jpg">three</option>'
```

And, to shorten this, you could replace the `foreach` loop with a simple [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) statement as follows:

```
shuffle($options); 
echo '<select class="selectpicker1...">';
echo implode("\n", $options); 
echo '</select>';
```

[**Demo!**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/mrq-9cx)

Comment: @MattHull to be clear, "interpolate" is a fancy way of saying "use the value of this variable instead of the literal string that happens to be the same as my variable name".  You either need to use double quotes, or remove the quotes(the latter is more efficient).

Comment: You are correct, this was an issue due to the $picker being in single quotes, however the code still isn't working as each img requires single quotes - <img src='img/render/1-thumb.jpg'> in order to work with the jquery. How can I overcome this?

Comment: use escapes. `echo "<a href=\"....\">...</a>";` Or use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) which eliminates the need to escape quotes in the text.

Comment: If you do double quotes inside single quotes, I believe you want `'<option data-content="<img src=\\"img/render/3-thumb.jpg\\">" 
value="3.jpg">three</option>'`. Because you want the final output to be `<option data-content="<img src=\"img/render/3-thumb.jpg\">" 
value="3.jpg">three</option>`

Comment: @Matt: What's wrong with the current approach? Did you check the demo?

Comment: Amazing, thank you all for all your help. Once again Stackoverflow is a great help!

Comment: @Amal Nothing, but that's an alternative with the proper escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's 2 things wrong with our code.

First thing wrong with your code is the array
use:

```
$options=['data1','data2','data3'];
```

not:

```
$options=array('data1','data2','data3')
```

second thing wrong with your code is string output(I think only works on mysql)
use:

```
echo $var;
```

not

```
echo '$var';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple option:**

Each of your options encoded like so in an array:

```
'<option data-type="<img src=\"img/render/5-thumb.jpg\">" value="5.jpg">five</option>'
```

Replace your `foreach` statement with an implode statement `echo implode('', $options);`

**More complex option**

Encode each option in their own array in the array, like so:

```
$options = array(
                array('img/render/5-thumb.jpg', '5.jpg'. 'five'),
                array('img/render/3-thumb.jpg', '3.jpg'. 'three'),
                array('img/render/1-thumb.jpg', '1.jpg'. 'one')
            );
```

Then replace your `foreach` statement with:

```
foreach ($options as $option) {
    echo '<option data-type="<img src=\"'.$option[0].'\">" value="'.$option[1]'">'.$option[2].'</option>';
}
```